# Change child image source using prototype js

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

How to change the icon path while click on parent link using prototype?

```html
<a onclick="toggleAmenity('park'); return false;" href="#">
    <input type="image" id="parks_button" src="/images/amenities/icon_parks.gif" name="commit">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are about a million ways to skin this cat, but this might give you some ideas using some Prototype stuff.

Instead of 'amenity' I'm using image size. Kinda confusing, but I wanted to show a visual change on click. I'd strongly advise against using onclick attributes for this type of thing (or most any other type of thing).

http://jsfiddle.net/gSfmL/

```
<p>
  <a data-toggle-amenity='64' href="#">
    <input type="image" id="parks_button" src="http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-128.png" name="commit">
  </a>
</p>

<p>
  <a href="#">This anchor won't fire</a>
</p>​
```

.

```
document.on('click', 'a[data-toggle-amenity]', function(event, element) {
  var amenityToggleType = element.readAttribute('data-toggle-amenity');
  element.down('input').writeAttribute({src: 'http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-' + amenityToggleType + '.png'});
  element.writeAttribute('data-toggle-amenity', null); // removes the attribute
});​
```